# IdentityServer4 with Sustainsys.Saml2 to make OAuth SAML Assertion

Tags: oauth-2.0, asp.net-core-2.0, saml-2.0, identityserver4, sustainsys-saml2

I have a problem to make sample which will fulfill RFC-7522. What I have is **IdentityServer4 (v2.2.0)** as oAuth **Authorization Server (.NET Core 2.0, Console Application)** and different SAML2 IdP. Now I want to use Saml Assertion to auth user.

As inspiration I used this [video](https://youtu.be/TZzFPhVkzo4?t=20m54s) where Brock Allen and Dominick Baier describes how to set up SAML2 handler.

But sadly, I'm stuck right at beginning where I want just paste that snippet to my code and every time I end up with different compilation error (depends on [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Sustainsys.Saml2/) I use). I've unfortunately had no luck in solving them.

**Snipet:**

```
//IServiceCollection services
services.AddAuthentication().AddSaml2(options =>
{
    options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
    options.SPOptions.EntityId = new Saml2NameIdentifier(samlIdentityUrl);

    var idp = new IdentityProvider(new EntityId(samlMetadataUrl), options.SPOptions)
    {
        SingleSignOnServiceUrl = new Uri(samlSignOnUrl),
        Binding = Saml2BindingType.HttpRedirect
    };

    idp.SigningKeys.AddConfiguredKey(new X509Certificate2(certificate));
    options.IdentityProviders.Add(idp);
});
```

**Common Nugets:**

- IdentityModel.Unoficial (2.8.1)
- IdentityServer4 (2.2.0)
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.All (2.0.3)
- Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml (5.2.4)
- Sustainsys.Saml2.AspNetCore2 (see below)

**Scenario #1: Sustainsys.Saml2.AspNetCore2 (0.24.0)**

Package 'Sustainsys.Saml2.AspNetCore2 0.24.0' was restored using '.NetFramework, Version=v4.6.1'.. what is referred in [this](https://github.com/Sustainsys/Saml2/issues/984) and [this](https://github.com/Sustainsys/Saml2/issues/881) issue. On top of that I have few compilation error which could be break to **'The type 'EntityId' and 'SecurityKeyIdentifierClause' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced.'**

**Scenario #2: Sustainsys.Saml2.AspNetCore2 (2.0.0-preview01)**

Missing whole Sustainsys namespace and it is replaced by Kentor.AuthServices. Reference .AddSaml2(..) not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fine, I was able to solve my problem by **update nugets and imports** to following state:

**Nugets:**

- IdentityServer4 (2.2.0)
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.All (2.0.3)
- Microsoft.IdentityModel.Token.Saml (5.2.4.)
- Sustainsys.Saml2 (2.0.0-preview01)
- Sustainsys.Saml2.AspNetCore2 (2.0.0-preview01)

**Imports:**

```
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2;
using Kentor.AuthServices;
using Kentor.AuthServices.Metadata;
using Kentor.AuthServices.WebSso;
```